# Redirection in Django URLs

Tags: django, django-urls, url-pattern

How do I redirect all URLs starting from a particular pattern to another?

Description:

I want to be able to redirect as follows:

```
/pattern1/step1/ to /pattern2/step1/
/pattern1/step2/ to /pattern2/step2/
/pattern1/continue/ to /pattern2/continue/
```

What is the easiest way of doing this in Django URL patterns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RedirectView works.  Capture the remainder of the path with a named kwarg.  It will be passed into `RedirectView.get_redirect_url`, so you can interpolate it into the url you provide.

```
url(r'^pattern1/(?P<url>.+)$', RedirectView.as_view(url="/pattern2/%(url)s")),
#                    ^                                                ^
#                    | this url                         appears here  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redirect_to` generic view and add redirection urls in urls.py as:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^pattern1/step1/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/pattern2/step1/'}),
    #any more patters.
)
```

Here is documentation: [Generic view redirect_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to) . These can take the parameters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Redirections could also be handled at the web server level.

Comment: Yes. I thought of this. But since this would be a frequent change, I wanted to check if there was a way to do this using Django itself. :)